Empty Spaces on PCB
I'm designing a PCB for the first time, and I've read it's good practice to fill blank spaces with pours, I've done this with the ground layer, but am unsure whether I should do it with the top layer too? So should I just do a pour across the whole top layer that isn't actually connected to anything? Are there downsides of doing this / not doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Are you sure the same hasn't been asked before? At least similar questions exist but maybe with a bit different aspect or wording. Do they apply to your scenario as well?

Have you read about why its good practice to fill in blank spaces, and if those reasons apply to the board you're designing?

The trace from R9 on bottom layer is cutting up your ground pour (I assume) on bottom layer. If you can’t avoid it, pour ground on top and stitch together with vias.

Filling blank spaces was important historically due to processing and material limitations (uneven copper fill on different layers could lead to warping). I've made plenty of boards with uneven fill in the last several years, and none of them have had the slightest issue, even over large temperature swings; I think the idea that you should fill in every part of the board might be obsolete.

Pouring a "large" copper pour on any layer and not having it be connected to anything,. ie. floating, is usually not a good idea.
I say usually because if it matters at all depends on the environment it will operate in, and the circuit itself. If it's a low power, low frequency digital circuit, you probably won't notice any difference.
In space or other radiation environments, floating metal is bad because it accumulates charge and will interact with surrounding circuits.
If the circuit is RF, it can also affect the impedances of surrounding circuits, unless it's used as part of coplanar waveguide techniques.
If the goal is to provide balanced copper to improve PCB yield, and reduce warping, you can use copper thieving.  Basically placing small floating copper features in a pattern that is too small to interact with surrounding circuits but also fills the area with a large overall copper area.
Here is an example of thieving.
You can also place solid copper, and then stich it to the ground plane (looks like the bottom layer in your case) with lots of vias.  This is a balance, because if you put too many vias, then you can break up your ground plane with all the clearances.
Finally you can do as above, but make it connected to the power net.  This is sort of like what they do in a 4 layer board.  It can have the benefit of acting like a high quality capacitor from power to ground.
